# How can I use tab completion in bash based on different attributes of the string I am searching?

Tags: bash, tab-completion

Right now, I am in the directory `migrate` in my current Rails project, and have the following migrations:

```
20140206000143_create_users.rb   20140206032051_create_comments.rb 
20140209232521_create_login.rb   20140206031331_create_photos.rb  
20140206034224_load_data.rb
```

I want to select `20140209232521_create_login.rb` using tab completion but it becomes complicated because I have to pay attention to where the different filenames differ. Is there any way to select the file I'm looking for quickly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not without the bash_completion package installed, but it is fairly rudimentary compared the zsh tab completion. The native tab-completion in zsh is streets ahead. Zsh will cycle through your files with each tab, or you can tab complete wildcards, for example 'vi *users' would expand to 'vi 20140206000143_create_users.rb'

Answer (score 1):

With Bash, using the `menu-complete` function instead of the normal `complete` make get you closer to what you want:

```
bind C-i:menu-complete
```

With this setting, pressing the `<tab>` key will cycle between possible completions.